# New articles don´t work in Joomla 3.3.3 anymore

Tags: joomla, seo, article

New articles don´t work anymore after Joomla 3.3.3 update. Every new article I try to do it fails to open it.

For example this article: http://eflexfuel.com/fi/lisatarvikkeet/asennuspaketti

But I noticed that non-seo friendly site works fine: http://eflexfuel.com/fi/?option=com_content&view=article&id=50:asennuspaketti&catid=22&Itemid=139&lang=fi

Same things happens every new article I try to make.

I have tried different template. Try to fix articles dates. I haven´t done any changes but installing the new update of Joomla. If somebody has any ideas I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please start flowing these steps:

1. Delete your Joomla Cache
2. Delete your Browser Cache
3. Clear session table of your database (via phpmyadmin)
4. Check that .htaccess exist in your ftp root directory and if not rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess
5. Try to switch to the default joomla template and see if it works, if yes there is something wrong in your template.

Good Luck!

Comment: Still don´t work. I noticed if I change the category to root category that the url will be http://eflexfuel.com/fi/asennuspaketti it works but not in sub-categories. So the problem is propably in categories? And for remainder that old articles work fine.

Comment: Do you have made any modifications to your .htaccess file?

Comment: No I haven´t.  It´s the original Joomla .htaccess file

Comment: I haven´t done anything else but updated Joomla. After that new articles didn´t work no more.

Comment: I managed to get everything working. I deleted menu items and articles which didn´t work, deleted caches, session table and did new menu items and articles and now everything works.